# Powershell Add-Content Creating Two Files

Tags: powershell

When I comment out the "real" code and use the Write-Host for debugging I get the expected results. Otherwise I end up with two files. One named as planned, i.e., **andrew.aboutme.html** and the second named as **W3Creports.andrew.aboutme.html** (note the undesirable prefix of W3Creports).

BOTH files have CONTENTS that are are identical.

Here's where I'm at...

```
$HtmlCheck += "https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc="
$doc = "http://www.example.com/www1/"
$WebRoot = "C:/inetpub/wwwroot/myname/www1/"

$ReportFolder = $WebRoot + "W3Creports"
New-Item $Reports -ItemType Directory -Force 
Get-ChildItem -Path $Reports -Include *.* -File -Recurse | foreach { $_.Delete()}

# get a list of folders, i.e., the web site folders...  ignore any folders that have numbers in name
$Sites = (Get-ChildItem -Path $WebRoot -Directory | Where-Object {$_.Name -match "^[^\d]"}).Name

foreach ($site in $Sites)
{
    $SitePath = $WebRoot + $site
    $Pages = Get-ChildItem -Path $SitePath -File | Where-Object {$_.Name -match ".*\.htm.$"}

    foreach ($page in $Pages)
    {
        $url = $HtmlCheck + $doc + $site + "/" + $page.Name
        #$WebResponse = Invoke-WebRequest $url
        $results = "?" #$WebResponse.AllElements | Where id -eq "results"| Select -ExpandProperty innerHTML 


        $detail1 = "boo"  #"<h3>$($site).$($page) </h3>"  
        $detail2 = "W3C Nu HTML Validator " + (Get-Date).ToString()

       # Write-Host "$($ReportFolder)/$($site).$($page.Name)" "hi"
        Add-Content "$($ReportFolder)/$($site).$($page.Name)" "hi"
        #Add-Content $reportfile $detail2
        #Add-Content $reportfile $results
    }
}
```

Comment: You create `$ReportFolder` inside `$WebRoot`, so it considered as one of `$Sites`. Thus, it also validated and reported.

Comment: Ah ha! Of course. Thanks. I've been staring at it too long.